# Tensorflow 170 times slower than Theano for RNN implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, theano, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement a RNN in Tensorflow (0.11), based on [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06939v4.pdf) paper.

They have a Theano implementation [here](https://github.com/hidasib/GRU4Rec), that I am comparing my implementation to. When I try to run their Theano implementation, it finishes 10 epochs in about 1 hour. My Tensorflow implementation needs about 17 hours just to finish 1 epoch. I am wondering if anyone could look at my code and tell me if there are some obvious problems that are slowing it down.

The purpose of the RNN is to predict the next item a user is going to click on, given his previous clicks. The items are represented by unique IDs that are given as input to the RNN as a 1-HOT vector.

So the RNN is built like this:

`[INPUT (1-HOT representation, size 37803)] -> [GRU layer (size 100)] -> [FeedForward layer]`

and the ouput from the FF layer is a vector with the same size as the input vector, where high values indicate that the item corresponding to that index is very likely to be the next one clicked.

```
num_hidden = 100

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_length, n_items], name="InputX")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_length, n_items], name="TargetY")
session_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name="SeqLenOfInput")

output, state = rnn.dynamic_rnn(
    rnn_cell.GRUCell(num_hidden),
    x,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    sequence_length=session_length
    )

layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden, n_items])),
         'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_items]))}

output = tf.reshape(output, [-1, num_hidden])
prediction = tf.matmul(output, layer['weights'])

y_flat = tf.reshape(y, [-1, n_items])

final_output = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y_flat)

cost = tf.reduce_sum(final_output)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
```

Both implementations are tested on the same hardware. Both implementations utilize the GPU.

EDIT:
The Theano model has the same structure. (1-HOT input -> GRU layer with 100 units -> FeedForward)
I tested the Theano version with the same parameters as I used in my model (using cross entropy for the loss, batch size=200, adam optimizer, with the same learning rate, no dropout in either model) but the speed difference is still the same.

EDIT (2016-12-07):
Using file queues to queue batches instead of using feed_dict helped alot.
I still need to do other optimizations to make it faster. Anyways, here is how I used file queues to make it faster.

```
# Create filename_queue
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(train_files, shuffle=True)

min_after_dequeue = 1024
capacity          = min_after_dequeue + 3*batch_size
examples_queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(
        capacity=capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue,
        dtypes=[tf.string])

# Create multiple readers to populate the queue of examples
enqueue_ops = []
for i in range(n_readers):
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    _key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    enqueue_ops.append(examples_queue.enqueue([value]))

tf.train.queue_runner.add_queue_runner(
        tf.train.queue_runner.QueueRunner(examples_queue, enqueue_ops))
example_string = examples_queue.dequeue()

# Default values, and type of the columns, first is sequence_length
# +1 since first field is sequence length
record_defaults = [[0]]*(max_sequence_length+1)

enqueue_examples = []
for thread_id in range(n_preprocess_threads):
    example = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

    # Split the row into input/target values
    sequence_length = example[0]
    features = example[1:-1]
    targets  = example[2:]

    enqueue_examples.append([sequence_length, features, targets])

# Batch together examples
session_length, x_unparsed, y_unparsed = tf.train.batch_join(
        enqueue_examples, 
        batch_size=batch_size,
        capacity=2*n_preprocess_threads*batch_size)


# Parse the examples in a batch
x = tf.one_hot(x_unparsed, depth=n_classes)
y = tf.one_hot(y_unparsed, depth=n_classes)

# From here on, x, y and session_length can be used in the model
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could summarize the theano version into something similar to your tensorflow example with the same parameters.

Comment: I have added an EDIT. The models are the same with respect to the layers. I have also tested with the same parameters in both, but it did not make any big difference. The speed difference is still HUGE no matter what parameters I have tried with. Could it simply be that Theano is much faster than Tensorflow in this case?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if theano beats tensorflow in terms of speed in some cases but an x170 factor is huge, I don't really see what could be the problem but if no one helps out here then it's worth opening an issue on Github.

Comment: It's not in the code, but I suspect you are using feed_dict in your session.run. Feed_dict can be inefficient because it forces TensorFlow to do copies between Python client and C++ runtime (but not for Theano because both client and runtime are Python). That wouldn't explain 170x difference though, I wonder if you are feeding whole dataset in your placeholder

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.
I do use feed_dict in my sess.run. I don't feed the whole dataset. But since I use 1-HOT vectors, then a batch of 200 would contain 200*10*2 vectors of size 37803. (10 input vectors and 10 target vectors in each batch). So I guess that could mount to some hundred MB.
Could you point me to a better way of feeding in the data?

Comment: What's the source of the data? If it's csv, you could use tf ops as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#file-formats) to read the data (and efficiently batch them as described later in that page). If you have some python-specific preprocessing then try saving the data into csv and use that method to see if it makes a difference. But first, it's better if you profile your code a bit to see where it's spending the most time (if possible).

Comment: @sirfz Thanks for the help. I followed the suggestions and used file queues instead of feed_dict to input the batches. Now the program only runs 10-15 times slower than the Theano implementation. The Theano implementation is pretty optimized, and I believe that it is possible to handle the big and sparse 1-hot vectors in a smarter way. I will add an edit to my post with the code I used, in case it helps someone else, and I will try profiling my code to find other possible optimizations.

Comment: That's great news, the difference still pretty big but it's a good start. Looking forward to hear more good news :)